# Using fortranmagic in IPython notebook for sorting an array: no return value

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, fortran

I have to say that I am not a Fortran-programmer at all. I usually only use Python and C++, but sometimes colleagues have written great Fortran functions that would be great to implement in my Python code for efficiency. I was just about to try the f2py module via IPython's magic function.

For a trivial test, I have the following bubblesort implementation where I want to sort a Python list in place (which I convert to an numpy array laid out in memory the Fortran-style; I assume this would be more efficient than using Python lists right?)

However, the function has no return value here (`None`), and I am wondering where my mistake would be!?

The commands to install and load the fortranmagic which uses f2py

```
%install_ext https://raw.github.com/mgaitan/fortran_magic/master/fortranmagic.py
%load_ext fortranmagic
```

The Fortran bubblesort code:

```
%%fortran
SUBROUTINE fortran_bubblesort(a)
  REAL, INTENT(in out), DIMENSION(:) :: a
  REAL :: temp
  INTEGER :: i, j
  LOGICAL :: swapped = .TRUE.

  DO j = SIZE(a)-1, 1, -1
    swapped = .FALSE.
    DO i = 1, j
      IF (a(i) > a(i+1)) THEN
        temp = a(i)
        a(i) = a(i+1)
        a(i+1) = temp
        swapped = .TRUE.
      END IF
    END DO
    IF (.NOT. swapped) EXIT
  END DO
END SUBROUTINE fortran_bubblesort
```

The execution:

```
x = np.asfortranarray([3,2,1])
y = fortran_bubblesort(x)
print(x, y)
```

The result:

```
[3 2 1] None
```

========

To test that a value can be returned in general, I ran the following code, which works just fine:

```
%%fortran
SUBROUTINE fortran_sum(x, y, z)
    REAL, INTENT(in) :: x,y
    REAL, INTENT(out) :: z

    z = x + y

END SUBROUTINE fortran_sum
```

Execute:

```
fortran_sum(3, 4)
```

Returns:

```
7.0
```

Comment: I don't know fortran but you are sorting a list in place not returning one so you would get None from printing the function.

Comment: It is a subroutine, like a void function it doesn't return anything. But shouldn't x be reversed?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing has to do with the array dimensions. It looks like that subroutine was yanked from a module, as it uses an assumed-shape dummy array `a`. This requires an explicit interface, and I don't know if and/or how `f2py` handles that. I've only ever used `f2py` using assumed size dummy arrays, which it handles well. This would be the code:

```
SUBROUTINE fortran_bubblesort(a,n)
  INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n
  REAL, INTENT(in out), DIMENSION(n) :: a
  REAL :: temp
  INTEGER :: i, j
  LOGICAL :: swapped = .TRUE.

  DO j = SIZE(a)-1, 1, -1
    swapped = .FALSE.
    DO i = 1, j
      IF (a(i) > a(i+1)) THEN
        temp = a(i)
        a(i) = a(i+1)
        a(i+1) = temp
        swapped = .TRUE.
      END IF
    END DO
    IF (.NOT. swapped) EXIT
  END DO
END SUBROUTINE fortran_bubblesort
```

In this case, `f2py` will notice that `n` is just the array dimension, and it will make it an optional argument in the python function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this. I tried it on numpy arrays and regular Python lists but with no success. I added a simple code for calculating a sum to the top section to test if it generally works...

Answer (score 0):

I made the original Fortran code of the question working by just replacing both "*REAL*" statements by "*REAL(kind=8)*" statements. That way, Fortran's variables match Python's ones.
Also, to get the execution working and to avoid the "*None*" output, I propose the following lines (note that I've changed the integer inputs by float data to have a correct match):

```
import numpy as np
x = np.asfortranarray([3.,0., 2.,1.])
print(x)
fortran_bubblesort(x)
print(x)
```

Execution:

> [ 3.  0.  2.  1.]
>   [ 0.  1.  2.  3.]

Note that I've also added number zero to be more Pythonic ;-)